# How to know which hook are implemented in gitolite & git server?

Tags: git, gitolite

Is there any way to know which hooks are implemented on my repository if I am a normal git (gitolite) user.
For example : Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that feature in the current [Gitolite commands](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/master/src/commands).

You could implement a [gitolite command](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#commands) which does that.
Or extend the [`info` command](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#user) in order to include the hooks associated to the repos accessible by the user making the request.
For each repo, that command script would look into `~/repositories/<arepo.git>/hooks`.